# VBS move files from download

Tags: vbscript, path, movefile

how to move a file from C:\Users\username\Downloads
is there a variable for username so that if it is on someone else his computer that it also works and that you don't need to chance the code. Because I can't acces the username so I can't move any files from the downlaods folder to an other folder. I look in windows command but there was no answer I have looked on the internet but there are more people with the same problem and also have no good answers. After 2 weeks I still do not know to path to the downloads folder with vbs. Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is but you shouldn't be using it. Environmental variables aren't for programs.

> There are a number of standard folders that are used frequently by
>   applications, but may not have the same name or location on any given
>   system. For example, the system folder may be "C:\Windows" on one
>   system and "C:\Winnt" on another. The values in this enumeration are
>   equivalent to the CSIDL values used in C++ applications. They provide
>   a unique system-independent way for applications to identify special
>   folders. **They supersede the use of environment variables for this
>   purpose**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/ne-shldisp-shellspecialfolderconstants

and to use

> ```
>     set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
>     set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("C:\\")
> ```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-namespace